# Magento 2 : Search For Admin Menu Items

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

In magento2 admin dashboard , We have an option for Search. When we search for "rma" for example it is showing "rma in products" , "rma in pages" etc but I need to know if rma found in any of the admin menus then it will come in search results. As we have almost 30 magento extensions installed for my store I am unable to access them properly from left menu. If any extension that provides this search for menus will helpful. If anybody knows about how to search for admin menus please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension for this purpose. It searches all the Menu links in admin via Ajax and returns results with information about its parent -> child hierarchy as well.

https://marketplace.magento.com/magehelper-menusearch.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The global search box in admin header can be used to find any record in the database. The results can include customers, pages, products, orders, or any related attribute and as a Magento developer, we all know that Magento doesn't store admin menus in the database. They are collected through the menu.xml files of all modules.

Comment: Any solution for this?